# Problem with smoke domain when resizing

Tags: fluid-simulation, smoke-simulation

Trying to create fire sim but ran into a bit of a problem. The fire domain doesn't encompass the area that I want it to but whenever I resize it and then re-bake it the size of the fire ball also changes. I haven't changed any of the settings in between bakes so I have no idea what could be causing this.

[image: Before resize]

[image: after resize]

Answer (score 1):

This happens because of the so called "resolution divisions".

From the docs:

Resolution Divisions
The fluid domain is subdivided into many “cells” called Voxels which make up “pixels” of fluid. This setting controls the number of subdivisions in the domain. Higher numbers of subdivisions are one way of creating higher resolution fluids.

Since the resolution is defined in terms of “subdivisions”, larger domains will need more divisions to get an equivalent resolution to a small domain. For example, a one meter cube with 64 Resolution Divisions will need 128 divisions to match a 2 meter cube. The dimension used as the base division is the longest dimension of the objects bounding box. To help visualize the voxel size, the Resolution Divisions can be previewed with a small cube shown in the 3D Viewport, to show the size of these divisions.

So if you change the size of your domain, you change the number of voxels in the domain - which changes the fluid/fire behaviour.

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.93/physics/fluid/type/domain/settings.html#smoke